# Javascript regexp for embed bbcode

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, bbcode

So am trying to do a basic bbcode parsing (just for embed tag) but it's been a while I didn't play around with regexp so I'm asking help on this one.
I'd like to match all `[embed]...[/embed]` so I use:

```js
var regexp = new RegExp(/\[embed\].*\[\/embed\]/ig);
console.log(regexp.test(content));
```

I got many `false` while I should only have `true`.
Jsfiddle available here : http://jsfiddle.net/5rxu5/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
var reg = new RegExp(/\[embed\](.*?)\[\/embed\]/i);
$('.wmd-output').each(function() {
    var content = $(this).html();
    alert(reg.test(content));
});
```

Here is the jsfiddle link which alerts true for all cases: http://jsfiddle.net/UVy45/

Answer (score 0):

```
var regexp = new RegExp(/\[embed\](.*)\[\/embed\]/ig);
console.log(regexp.test(content));
```

Comment: Alerting the same `false` in the jsfiddle.